# How to add label to bent arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-arrows, arrows, labels

I use this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[place,
            accepting,
            label=above:$p_1^1$] (p11) at (-3,0) {};
        \node[transition,
            minimum width=1.5mm,
            minimum height=12mm,
            label=below:$t_1$] (t1) at (-1.5,0) {};
        \draw[thick] (p11) edge[post,bend left=30] (t1) 
            (t1) edge[post,bend left=30] (p11);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to add a label to each arrow, preferably like this:

[image: simple pnet with arrow labels]

I have tried using `{label}` after the receiving nodes of each arrow but it does not work.

Comment: Hello. As a rule on this site, please provide a *complete* (yet short) example, so that people can copy-paste it and compile it straight away. Not only is it more polite for the people who try to help you, it's also necessary to see which packages you're using. Thanks.

Comment: For example `(p11) edge[...] node [above] {$q^1$} (t1)` I suppose? (As in e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538590/midway-label-for-edge/538635#538635)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.